# Parsing PHP-style request params

Tags: asp.net

I'm looking for a way to parse PHP-style request parameters in an ASP.NET app. Specifically, I'd like to parse `foo[]=42&foo[]=666` into an array `{142, 666}`.

What's the simplest way to do that in ASP.NET?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
string[] foo = Request.QueryString.GetValues("foo[]");
```

Comment: This is the approach I ended up using. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use string.Split with the '&' and then again with the '='. Then just populate a list with the values.